# Working with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I just started learning how to write htaccess .
I got the following code from [this page](http://anantgarg.com/2009/03/13/write-your-own-php-mvc-framework-part-1/), which redirects everything to an index.php file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) public/    [L]
</IfModule>
```

I understood all lines except `^$    public/    [L]` and `(.*) public/    [L]`.What does they mean.To me it looks like some regular epression :)..
I know RewriteRule is used for writing rules for redirecting .But what do symbols $ ,(,),., * etc. indicate ?.
When I put these lines to .htaccess I got the following error

> [image]

But when I comment the 4th line,it is working..ie .the following code is working

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
    #RewriteRule    (.*) public/    [L]
</IfModule
```

So what is the problem here?

Comment: do not pollute tags with irrelevant ones, like "PHP" or "MVC"

Comment: public is the directory. L means if this rewriterule caught the request then this is the Last line htaccess is to run so bail out

Comment: ^$ means empty string. it will evaluate to ./public/ because it's not looking for a file.

Comment: Also it is always worth using Fiddler http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ to watch what happens with the headers when visiting the URL. Redirect loops become clear as day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you are inside rewrite loop like blew:
you rewrite abc.com/anything to abc.com/public and also you are rewriting /public to /public.
maybe you should specify which url must be rewrite . (limit your requests) like this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^index.php(.*)$ public/$1    [NC,L]
```

rewrites index.php?requests to public/?requests

Comment: [NC,L] means that the rule is non case sensitive and the last rule that these conditions match

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer to your first question, for the second, you should provide us with more information (like a log entry from `/var/log/apache2/error.log`)

`^` matches the beginning of a string

`$` matches the end of a string

`^$` matches an empty string

`.` matches any character

`*` allows 0 to any number of occurrances of the preceding match

`(` and `)` mark a group that can be referenced later

`(.*)` will match any number of characters

Comment: Really helpful...so "." means  all  characters including special characters .,/...etc. ?

Comment: Finally I got the following tutorials on .htaccess
http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/php-variables-htaccess.html
http://www.widexl.com/tutorials/mod_rewrite.html